# How to pass value from php get in url ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I´m trying to pass value from php to ajax url

This is my code:

```
<?php


$id = $_GET['id'];

echo id;

?>
```

Code for javascript

```
$.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:3000/product/"+'<?$id; ?>',

    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json', 
    crossDomain: "true",      
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.type == false) {
            alert("Error occured:" + result.data);
            return false;
        }
        $.each(JSON.parse(result.data),function(index,obj){
      console.log(obj.id);
```

I´m getting error in 
http://localhost:3000/product/%3C?=$id;%20?%

Comment: Have you written jquery code in `.js` file

Comment: No in html file

Comment: You're missing a `?` in the URL. It should end up being `http://localhost:3000/product/?id=1234` for your PHP to work.

Comment: you should use like this `url:"http://localhost:3000/product/<?=$id; ?>",` or `url:"http://localhost:3000/product/?id=<?=$id; ?>",`

Comment: Try this `url:"http://localhost:3000/product/?id=<?=$id; ?>"`

Comment: As a side note, it looks like your PHP isn't being parsed, probably because you're doing this in a .html file instead of a .php file, or your server isn't set up to run PHP.

Comment: try url only /product/"+'<?=$id; ?>'

Comment: set that id in html element like hidden then access in script with getelementbyid & then pass it to url must be .php bcz without .php exetension you will not get the php veritable <?=$id?>

Comment: What is up with everyone saying to output the $id by `<?=$id; ?>`. That is wrong there should not be a semicolon! `<?=$id ?>`

Comment: @Adder that is irrelevant. The php is clearly not being compiled and is being passed to js as literal string

Comment: I´m getting this using what you say @PankajMakwana             jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:3000/product/%3C?=$id;%20?%3E 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Are you using php file or html file? it seems you are using .html file?

Comment: I´m using html file because backend is in nodejs

Comment: Unless you've configured it specifically to do so, PHP will not be parsed or run in a .html file. And if the backend is nodejs, why are you doing PHP :P

Comment: @Hari dont work your code

Comment: Why are you writing php at all when your back end is node?

Comment: I´m using php to using get values parameters because of redirections and it´s more simple using values from gets or sessions

Comment: after echo you can also store your id in a hidden input and then get that value and use in your ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the name of the parameter, try:

```
url:"http://localhost:3000/product?id=" + id',
```

If you want to get the id from php do:

```
id = <?php echo $id; ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

url: urlCall + '?' + $.param({"id": id}),

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<script>
var getid = '<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>';
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:3000/product?id="+getid',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json', 
    crossDomain: "true",      
   success: function (result) {
        if (result.type == false) {
        alert("Error occured:" + result.data);
        return false;
    }
    $.each(JSON.parse(result.data),function(index,obj){
  console.log(obj.id);
});
</script>
```